# How to modify navigation bar

Tags: html, css, forums, xenforo

How do I make the navigation bar make the selected page be a different color than the other tabs? I am using Xenforo so it uses xenforo code, HTML, and CSS.

I am okay with HTML and CSS however I do not know how to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Trevor

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with CSS. If your navigation looks something like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active">Home</li>
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
</ul>
```

Then all you have to do is change the style for the "active" item, like this:

```
.nav li {
  //regular style
}
.nav li.active {
   //do something different!
   color: red; //change the color to red
   background-color: #999; //change the background color to light grey
}
```

You just have to set the `class="active"` for each page to mark which page you're on.

Comment: Appreciated, however the Xenforo default code for navigation.css and navigation is crazy complicated (to me) so I wouldn't know how to properly modify it.